# Why can't I bind-mount "/" inside a user namespace?

Tags: mount, namespace, bind-mount, userns

Why doesn't this work?

```
$ unshare -rm mount --bind / /mnt
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

These work ok:

```
$ unshare -rm mount --bind /tmp /mnt
$ unshare -rm mount --bind /root /mnt
$
```

---

```
$ uname -r  # Linux kernel version
4.17.3-200.fc28.x86_64
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference is that `/` has child mounts.  Inside a user namespace, you are not allowed to separate inherited mounts from their child mounts.  A more obvious example is that you are not allowed to `umount /proc`.  Otherwise, it could suddenly grant you access to files that were hidden underneath other mounts.  Overmounts are sometimes used deliberately as a security measure.

You are allowed to create a recursive bind mount instead, which preserves all the sub-mounts:

```
$ unshare -rm mount --rbind / /mnt
```